# Do others see the same spin up of an electron as me?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, observers

imagine I made a measurement of an electron and revealed that it is spin up, however in the room with me are hundreds of cameras and some of which are oriented at different angles. Maybe some are held upside down and some at 15.25°, etc you get the drift. Since I didn't label the directions on my apparatus so that only I can tell the difference between spin up and spin down, could the other cameras be able to saw the measurement and confirms with my result especially the up-side down camera?

Answer (score 1):

If we try to repeat a quantum measurement, then we might get a different result depending on whether we are performing exactly the same or a different measurement. For spin measurements we are very likely to get different results. The determining factor here is not in which direction a camera is pointing, but in which direction a magnetic field (gradient) is pointing. So if you don't tell anybody the direction of your magnetic field and they try to repeat your measurement with a magnetic field pointing in a different direction, then the second, third etc. measurements will likely return different outcomes. Only if the fields are all aligned can all measurement outcomes be the same.

Comment: This answer is currently unclear: the first and second sentences are in contradiction.  If a “quantum measurement can only be made once” then surely one cannot “try to do it again”.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero You are absolutely right. That was a really poor language choice. I assume you know what I meant. Any suggestions to how to improve the answer? I might just remove the first sentence for now and think about what I was trying to express for some time. If you can come up with a good way of putting it, please don't hesitate to edit.

Comment: Would your answer hold for a magnet, where electron spin is purposefully polarized?

Comment: @foolishmuse I hope the language holds but I will check. Phenomenologically repeated use of a Stern-Gerlach experiment on an electron beam at 90 degree angles will keep splitting the beams, i.e. even a completely polarized beam with just the up projection in one direction will keep slitting equally in two beams, then four and so on. This is usually taken as proof that spin can not be treated as a classical mixed ensemble. (And, yes, I am aware that a Stern-Gerlach doesn't really work on charged beams. It was originally carried out on neutral silver atom, if I remember correctly.)